# Sharing Folder API

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, shared-directory

I have C# WinForm application that needs to set sharing permission to some folder, and specify what users have access read/write/delete. 
I was wondering if there is any api or way to call something similar to when you right click on folder select Properties/Sharing/Advanced Sharing and window opens.

[image: Advanced Sharing Window]

If you know of anyway calling this window from c# I would appreciate if you share your knowledge. 
I want to call this window.

Comment: Are you asking if its possible to show this dialog for the user to interact with, or how to implement the dialogs functionality in code?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it through Win32 API:

```
private static void QshareFolder(string FolderPath, string ShareName, string Description)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a ManagementClass object
            ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");

            // Create ManagementBaseObjects for in and out parameters
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            ManagementBaseObject outParams;

            // Set the input parameters
            inParams["Description"] = Description;
            inParams["Name"] = ShareName;
            inParams["Path"] = FolderPath;
            inParams["Type"] = 0x0; // Disk Drive

            // Invoke the method on the ManagementClass object
            outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
            if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to share directory.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error!");
        }
    }
```

Usage:
    QshareFolder("c:\TestShare", "Test Share", "This is a Test Share");

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18624/How-to-Share-Windows-Folders-Using-C

Comment: At least clean up the code and get rid of all the extra spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can't set Permissions for specific users using QShareFolder. I want to invoke build in Advance Share Folder if possible. Why reinvent the wheel if it's already exist.

Comment: @Farukh check this out http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?616267-Creating-shared-folders-and-specifying-share-permissions and maybe convert the code using http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 3):

There is no any standart API for this task.

Try this project to implement what you need [How to Share Windows Folders Using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18624/How-to-Share-Windows-Folders-Using-C) (and here there is another example https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/de213b61-dc7e-4f33-acdb-893aa96837fa/c-set-directory-sharing-permission-full-control-for-everyone-programmatically-in-windows-7-or?forum=windowssdk)

Notice that your application will need to be running with Administrative access in order to share a folder.